# Custom field in OTRS 5 Ticket

Tags: otrs

I want to add a field like Department name in OTRS 5 customer's ticket view.So when they create a new ticket they can select department name.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and what specific problem you are having.

Comment: I have tried adding department name by going to Advance > Sysconfig > Ticket > Frontend::Customer::Ticket::ViewNew.Then in bottom of this page i added department name on Dynamic field, am i doing correct ?

Comment: Have you defined a dynamic field with according name in Admin -> Dynamic fields ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to define new Dynamic Field (if you would like to have predefined options, you should use Dropdown). To do this you need to go to *Admin->Dynamic Fields* and than in Ticket section you need to choose appropriate type of DF.

Once you have your DF defined you need to go to  *Sysconfig->Ticket-> Frontend::Customer::Ticket::ViewNew* and in **Ticket::Frontend::CustomerTicketMessage###DynamicField** hash you should add name of DF as key and 1 or 2 as value (setting 2 will make field required on the form).

Comment: Thanks now i am able to add dynamic field like IP address in otrs.